# Unhandheld Exception: System.Indexoutofbound exception: Index was outside the bound of array

Tags: c#

I am trying to write the code for splitting first char from a string like:
Input is = `This Is Stackoverflow`
Output(which i want)= `TIS`
But i am getting `Unhandheld Exception: System.Indexoutofbound exception: Index was outside the bound of array`

//my code is

```
using System;
public class n2
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {

        String s1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
        s1=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
        char[] charArr=s1.ToCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<s1.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(charArr[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s1.Length);
        char[] n1= new char[s1.Length];
        n1[0]=charArr[0];

        for(int j=1;j<s1.Length-1;j++)
        {               
                if(charArr[j]==' ')
                {   
                for(int k=1;k<10;k++)
                    {       
                        n1[k]=charArr[++j];
                    }
                          }     
        }

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Console.Write(n1[i]);
        }   

    }
}
```

I dont know the mistake, please provide suggestions.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: In second for loop variable j is incremented twice. Which is causing that exception.

Comment: I suggest that you learn to debug. It's an important skill. I suppose the downvotes you got were because you didn't try to debug it yourself, which would have easily solved your problem.

Comment: The task reads like some kind of homework ^^ Isn't your favorite-course, @neeraj, is it?

Comment: Yes started learning this just now, thats why facing problem@Patric

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: As well as the problem with 'j', there's an algorithm problem (!) if there's a space in the last 10 characters. I'm not really sure what the point of that inner loop is. Also, pick better names (it is really hard though): 's1', 'charArr' and 'n1' don't really say what they're for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate reason of the error is in the

```
  n1[k]=charArr[++j];
```

However, *regular expressions* and *Linq* seem to be a better approach here:

```
  String source = "This Is Stackoverflow";

  // "TIS"
  String result = String.Join("", Regex
    .Matches(source, @"(^| )\w")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in line `n1[k]=charArr[++j];` You need to check value of `j` before `charArr[++j]` in `if` clause. Something as follows,

```
if(j<s1.Length-1)
{
   n1[k]=charArr[j++]; //doing post increment!
}
```